# Checking 2d point is on which side of contour defined by a vector of points

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry, line, contour

I have a contour defined by a vector of points i.e. I have a vector of (x_i ,y_i).

Now given any point (a,b) is there a fast way to determine (a,b) lies on the same side as the origin (0,0) or not ?

The vector which defines the contour is a vector of roughly 7000 points. So determination using point by point maybe extremely slow. It would be very kind if someone can give any pointers.

(I am using visual C++ for my computations)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many queries do you have to answer? Have you actually measured that standard, linear algorithm is too slow? CPUs are surprisingly good at linear array scans :)

Comment: I am trying to integrate. For each point of the integrand I will have to check if it is on the correct side of contour. The grid over which integration happens 100K points.

Comment: Do you want to integrate over that polygon or is it just an argument to the integrated function?

Comment: If you are zeroing the points on incorrect side isn't it just integration over that polygon? Or maybe you want to integrate over box without that polygon?

Comment: it is not really a polygon because the contour is smooth and winding and has significant curvature. moreover the contour may keep changing from one integration to the next. to figure out the bounds of the polygon will be more difficult problem to solve.

Comment: So let me rephrase it: do you want to integrate over some *shape*?

Comment: yes, integrate over shape

Comment: I do not know what "on the same side as the origin" means. Determining if a point is within a closed polygon or outside of it runs pretty fast. When the polygon has a lot of folds in it then it is not overly easy, but still computationally doable. Additional considerations I needed to make were, "What is the point is on a line, or right next to one"? so once you know whether some points are inside or outside of a polygon, then what was the goal again? And how does that origin factor into the question?

Comment: If you are computing this for a grid then why not treat it as you would an array of pixels? Draw the contour onto it and then flood-fill from the origin to find all the points on the same side.

Comment: Beware that for an open curve, "on the same side" is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that preprocessing is allowed (otherwise you cannot avoid the "point by point" procedure).

A simple way is by scanning the polyline to decompose it in monotonous sections, i.e. such that the vertices appear by increasing or decreasing `x`. This takes linear time.

Then when you want to compare a point to the polyline, compare it to every monotonous section independently and find the `x` interval it faces, by dichotomic search. For a section of length `m`, this takes `Log m` operations. When you know the interval, you can immediately tell on what side ot the section you lie.

Repeat for all sections and count the number of "below", the parity of which gives you the answer.

This procedure takes time `s Log m` for `s` sections of length `m` (on geometric average). It is not worst-case optimal but is simple and will behave very decently on most cases.

[image]